# Month Differences in qlikview

Tags: expression, formula, qlikview

There is 2 dates column one is  **from date** and second is **to date** .. and i want to get month difference from these two dates

like if

```
from date      to date        month difference

01-02-2019  02-02-2020           13
```

here 02 (feb) month 2019 till 02 (feb) moth 2020 so this means total 13 months covered..

i tried this but this shows wrong results

```
month(from date) - month(to date)
```

and i also try this

```
month([from date] - [to date])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been using the code below for this case.

It basically converts both dates to months and returns the difference.

First the `Year` component of the date is "converted" to months (`year([to date]) * 12` part) and second adds the month number of the date (`month([to date]`)

```
Num (
    ( (year([to date]) * 12) + month([to date]) ) 
  - ( ((year([from date]) * 12) + month([from date])) ) + 1
)
```

UPDATE:

below is a screenshot of the result table with 2 expressions - including the `+1` and excluding it. Depends how you want to calculate the full months `+1` will "include" the last month as well

[image: Result table]

Comment: but if i have only 1 month ie. if i have from date 01-01-2019 and to date is 31-01-2019 then difference should be 0 not 1.. and in data i have dates 13-02-2018 and todate 12-09-2018 this show difference like -84,006 .. why this is happening ?

Comment: Added screenshot with the result im getting. You can remove the `+1` from the second calculation if you want to get `0` for dates in the same month. Im not quite sure why are you getting  `-84,006` possible mismatch in the dates? (like wrong format of the date, null date) Make sure that the date fields are contains dates and not strings that look like dates